# React native- how to fix the error [android build failed]

Tags: react-native

[This is my error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy78h.png)

My android build is getting failed. How to fix the error.This is my code.

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
 }
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  //From node_modules
}
```

Comment: it's not about your android `build.gradle`, there's an error in the lib `build.gradle`